# Como receber e manipular dados vindos do navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Minha dúvida é com relação a comunicação com o navegador. Como fazer, por exemplo, um programa que receba uma notificação sempre que alguém comentar seu post no *Facebook*? Já vi alguém fazer isto, no qual recebia no console do PC um aviso que foi comentado tal post. E como é feito o caminho inverso, ou seja, mandar entradas para o navegador?

Comment: não tem nada haver com navegador, navegador é apenas um cliente, deve ser a API do facebook em um aplicativo ou extensão.

Comment: vc precisa usar a API do Facebook